For a private network, are bootnodes required to be validators when initializing a chain?
I'm using hyperledger besu with QBFT to create a private network. I tested the following configurations:
A) 1 bootnode + 4 validator nodes (4 validators listed in the genesis file)
B) 1 bootnode that is also a validator + 3 validator nodes (all listed in the genesis file)
I found that with configuration B, my validator nodes began creating blocks and reaching consensus pretty quick, but with configuration A, all my validator nodes were able to connect to the boot node, but did not start creating blocks and didn't seem to find each other.
Is this expected behavior?
